# Button input submit is doing nothing

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to make a button to send a newsletter (only for test) but nothing happens i dont get any error message. can someone explain what i am doing wrong?

```
export default function Footer() {
    const [state, setState] = useState<string>();

    async function handleOnSubmit(e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setState('loading');
        await fetch('/api/email', {
            method: 'POST',
        })
        setState('ready');
    }

    return (
        <footer className="bg-blue-900 text-white">
            <div className="container mx-auto py-6">
                <div className="text-center mb-6">
                    <p className="mb-4">
                        <span className="mr-4">Nieuwsbrief</span>
                        <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
                            <input
                                type="email"
                                id="email"
                                placeholder="Email address"
                                className="bg-gray-200 rounded px-3 py-2 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
                            />
                        <button type="submit">Inschrijven</button>
                        </form>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    )
}
```

this is the route.ts this work how did i test it i change the POST to GET when i typed the url i got a email inside my emailbox

```
import { Resend } from 'resend';
import { welcomeEmail } from '@/app/emails/welcome';
import {NextResponse} from "next/server";

const resend = new Resend('apitoken');

export async function POST(){
    await resend.sendEmail({
        from: 'onboarding@resend.dev',
        to: 'fake@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Newsletter',
        react: welcomeEmail()
    });

    return NextResponse.json({
        status: 'ok'
    })
}
```

here is an image of my folder structure
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the button `type="submit"` as well

```
 <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
       <input
        type="email"
        id="email"
        placeholder="Email address"
        className="bg-gray-200 rounded px-3 py-2 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
        />
       <button type="submit">Inschrijven</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: I did that but also nothing happens.

Comment: Can you put a console.log in the handleOnSubmit to check if that method is now being called or not?

Comment: Hi when i put the console log nothing happens 

//this work
console.log('Form submitted');

export default function Footer() {
    //this doesnt work
    console.log('Form submitted');
    async function handleOnSubmit(e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('Form submitted'); 
        setState('loading');
        await fetch('/api/email', {
            method: 'POST',
        })
        setState('ready');
        console.log('Form submitted');
    }

    console.log(handleOnSubmit());

Comment: Hi ,i ran this code on my vs code and it gave me a console.log inside the handleOnSubmit function

Comment: Can you share your code Plz why does it not run on me?

Comment: I copied your code and ran it.
Can you create a sandbox of the above code and share that with me?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reaction your solution did work. There was something wrong with my file idk how.